# Where does the bonus feat in the cleric starting package come from?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, cleric

I am creating a human cleric. While doing so, I noticed that in the starting package for cleric (PHB I, p. 33), there is a "Bonus feat":

> **Feat**: Scribe Scroll.
>
> ***Bonus Feat**: Alertness.*
>
> **Deity/Domains**: Pelor/Good and Healing.
>
> **Gear**: Backpack with waterskin, one day's trail rations, bedroll, sack, and flint and steel. Case with 10 crossbow bolts. Wooden holy symbol (sun disc of Pelor). Three torches.
>
> **Gold**: 1d4 gp.

Where does this bonus feat come from? I mean, the section on class feat only states the weapon focus feat relative to the deity chosen.

Comment: Hi @vicaba - your image seems to have gone missing. Are you referring to something written in the books/reference documents or are you using a tool of some kind to create your character?

Comment: Hi, @Carcer. I'm referring to something written in the reference books. I've attached the image.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I've converted your image of text to just text for accessibility reasons, and added the page number it's from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Player's Handbook* cleric starting package does say it's for humans in the previous  column on the same page (33). It says **Human Cleric Starting Package** immediately before the Armor and Weapons entries.

The bonus feat is the suggested human bonus feat as per Human Racial Traits (13).

Answer (score 3):

As a human, you get an additional feat at first level.

Comment: Yes, I thought it could be that, but the sarter package doesn’t state that it has to be a human

Comment: Variant humans are 5e. This question is about 3.5e.

Comment: @nick012000 Looks like that was an edit. I'll fix.

Comment: @Jadasc Completely my mistake, when I picked this up in the review queue my brain missed the edition tag.  I owe you a beer.